# Seperate elements in span with comma/And for last element

Tags: html, angularjs

```
    <td>
    <span ng-repeat="rules in ruleTypes |filter:myFilter(client.clientId)">{{rules.rtid.ruleType}} ,</span>
</td>
```

The last element in span is also displaying comma, list is list A,B,C,D,
i want list like A, B, C, D Or A, B, C and D

Answer (score 1):

use a ng-if condition `<span ng-if="$index != ruleTypes.length-1"> , &nbsp;</span>`.

Also, use `&nbsp;` to add space in the HTML. and

```
<span ng-repeat="rules in ruleTypes |filter:myFilter(client.clientId)">{{rules.rtid.ruleType}} <span ng-if="$index != ruleTypes.length-1"> , &nbsp;</span> </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$last` that will be true if you come to last element of collection

```
<td>
    <span ng-repeat="rules in ruleTypes |filter:myFilter(client.clientId)">
        {{rules.rtid.ruleType}} 
        <span ng-if="!$last">,</span>
    </span>
</td>
```

There are also similar approaches to other usages, you can check out at angular docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Glad it helped. Just upvote/mark answer correct so it helps other people too.

Comment: @SAJALMATHUR I think you can do it now as you have rep 16